# Definition of ∈ as a binary relation?

Tags: set-theory

[This](https://courses-archive.maths.ox.ac.uk/node/view_material/47090) defines the “element of” or set membership symbol as a binary relation, supposed to denote the membership relation $ x \in X $. (Top of page 3)

As I understand, relations are subsets of Cartesian products, defined $$ A \times B = \{(a,b) \mid (a \in A) \land (b \in B)\} $$

So the definition of “$\in$” seems to use and depend on “$\in$” being already defined.

Am I mis-understanding this definition? Is there another definition that is not circular?

Furthermore, the same problem occurs a second time:  If relation $R =\, \in$, then, letting $x$ come from some universal set A, and B be a set of sets containing $X$, we have  $ xRX $ IFF $ (x,X) \in R \subseteq A\times B$, which again uses the symbol in its own definition.

Comment: As sets and elements are not defined, also $\in$ is not defined: it must be seen as a primitive object used to define all other things.

Comment: The symbol $\in$ is not defined, it is introduced as a primitive predicate of set theoretic language, along with logical symbols. "A binary relation which is supposed to denote the membership relation between two sets" is not a definition, it is an informal description of what it is supposed to represent intuitively. Relations as sets are not even introduced formally at that point.

Comment: Ah, ok, so it was my misunderstanding that this was a definition. And it is not defined, it is a primitive object. Thanks guys.